# Trouble with bitshift operations

Tags: c#, algorithm, byte, bit-shift

I try to realize hashing from local standart.
But it return wrong results in simple shift functions. I tried shift message:

```
byte[] test = Hash.StringToByteArrayFastest("EFCDAB8967452301");
Console.WriteLine(ToHex(Hash.ShLo(test)));
Console.WriteLine(ToHex(Hash.ShHi(test)));
```

And I expect to get:

```
ShLo : 77E6D5C4B3A2918016
ShHi : DF9B5712CE8A460216
```

but get this:

```
ShLo : f7e6d5c4b3a29100
ShHi : de9b5713cf8a4602
```

Here's my code

```
public static byte[] ShHi(byte[] B)
{
    return BitConverter.GetBytes(BitConverter.ToUInt64(B, 0) << 1);
}
public static byte[] ShLo(byte[] B)
{
    return BitConverter.GetBytes(BitConverter.ToUInt64(B, 0) >> 1);
}
public static byte[] StringToByteArrayFastest(string hex)
{
    if (hex.Length % 2 == 1)
        throw new Exception("The binary key cannot have an odd number of digits");
    byte[] arr = new byte[hex.Length >> 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < hex.Length >> 1; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = (byte)((GetHexVal(hex[i << 1]) << 4) + (GetHexVal(hex[(i << 1) + 1])));
    }
    return arr;
}
public static int GetHexVal(char hex)
{
    int val = (int)hex;
    return val - (val < 58 ? 48 : 55);
}
public static string ToHex(byte[] bytes)
{
    char[] c = new char[bytes.Length * 2];
    byte b;
    for (int bx = 0, cx = 0; bx < bytes.Length; ++bx, ++cx)
    {
        b = ((byte)(bytes[bx] >> 4));
        c[cx] = (char)(b > 9 ? b + 0x37 + 0x20 : b + 0x30);
        b = ((byte)(bytes[bx] & 0x0F));
        c[++cx] = (char)(b > 9 ? b + 0x37 + 0x20 : b + 0x30);
    }
    return new string(c);
}
```

Comment: When you convert your string to `byte[]`, it represents `0x0123456789abcdef`. Makes sense?

Comment: @IvanStoev how can I fix it?

Comment: Modify the `StringToByteArrayFastest` to populate the array in reverse order of what are you doing currently.

Comment: @IvanStoev can you fix it? I've got the same error

Comment: @IvanStoev But now i've got 776e5d4c3b2a1908 and fdb97521eca86420

Comment: Sorry, you are right. But you got the idea, hope you have solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static string ToHex(byte[] bytes)
{
    char[] c = new char[bytes.Length * 2];
    byte b;
    for (int bx = 0, cx = c.Length - 1; bx < bytes.Length; ++bx)
    {
        b = ((byte)(bytes[bx] & 0x0F));
        c[cx--] = (char)(b > 9 ? b + 0x37 + 0x20 : b + 0x30);
        b = ((byte)(bytes[bx] >> 4));
        c[cx--] = (char)(b > 9 ? b + 0x37 + 0x20 : b + 0x30);
    }
    return new string(c);
}
public static byte[] StringToByteArrayFastest(string hex)
{
    if (hex.Length % 2 == 1) throw new Exception("The binary key cannot have an odd number of digits");
    byte[] arr = new byte[hex.Length >> 1];
    for (int i = 0, j = arr.Length - 1; i < arr.Length; ++i)
    {
        arr[j--] = (byte)((GetHexVal(hex[i << 1]) << 4) + (GetHexVal(hex[(i << 1) + 1])));
    }
    return arr;
}
```